# What's a good and reliable database on the pharmacodynamic and pharmacokinetic data of drugs both approved and unapproved?

Tags: pharmacology, database

What's a good and reliable database for the pharmacodynamic and pharmacokinetic data of drugs both approved (in the US and elsewhere) and unapproved?

Answer (score 2):

For approved drugs, the **Drugs @FDA** database at [CDER](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/) (Center for Drug Evaluation and Research) aggregates labeling information (which includes at least a cursory PD explanation and a listing of or reference to common PK data for the substance) for most modern drugs.

Unapproved drugs may be a bit trickier to find out about, but the FDA maintains a list of contract research organizations (CROs) who are running trials [here](http://www.fda.gov/Drugs/InformationOnDrugs/ucm135162.htm), and the actual trials can be found on http://www.clinicaltrials.gov/, which will have citations for the papers that have been published.

Drugs in their earliest stages of development, i.e., internal to a pharma company, are likely to be kept pretty tightly under wraps.

I don't know enough about the governing bodies in other countries to know where any international data would be, but I assume you can find published papers for substances in those countries as well.

Comment: Where exactly on this site do you find the PD and PK data? I looked up sertraline all I got was these sort of pages...http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/drugsatfda/index.cfm?fuseaction=Search.Overview

Comment: If you go to the brand for the drug (Zoloft), click on the pill form, and then click on the "label data", it will come up.  On the main screen with the brand drugs, it also has a link that says "label available"  (they aren't labels any longer, but those inserts that manufacturers put in, but they retain the old name).

Comment: @BrentonHorne The generics don't need labeling info, only bioequivalence, so I think the information for PK is retained with the original IND number.

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd recommend volunteering in a university lab, because you clearly have a strong passion for this with all of your questions!

Answer (score 0):

Before I asked this question I knew of a website that provides reliable (from the US government) pharmacodynamic and pharmacokinetic data for FDA-approved drugs: [DailyMed](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/about.cfm?). I didn't accept it as an answer because of the fact that it is just FDA-approved drugs but I'm interested in other drugs like moclobemide, tianeptine, piracetam, aniracetam, nefopam, flupirtine and levomepromazine too.